# Среднее арифметическое из повторов рангов массива

Tags: c#

Допустим есть одномерный массив чисел. Мне нужно заполнить второй массив рангами этих чисел. Наименьшее получает ранг 1, следующее по порядку 2 и т.п. Если число встречается несколько раз, каждое его вхождение получает средний ранг для этого числа (т.е. среднее арифметическое из повторов этого числа).

Пока получилось заполнить рангами второй массив, но средний ранг отрабатывает правильно только для случая когда число встречается два раза, а если повторов больше, то результат уже с ошибкой.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как скорректироваться на число повторов n?

```
int[] scores = new int[] { 400, 651, 829, 651, 400, 405, 400 };
int pos = 0;
var res = scores.Join(
    scores.GroupBy(g => g)
 .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
 .Select(s => { pos += s.Count(); return new { Score = s.Key, Rang = ((double)2 * pos - s.Count() + 1) / 2 }; }), 
  i => i, o => o.Score, (o, i) => new { Score = o, Rang = i.Rang });

foreach (var result in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.Score, result.Rang);
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Ну вроде же правильно показывает, нет? У вас 400 встречается 3 раза, (1+2+3)/3=2

Comment: точно, я туплю уже...сорри

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас как-то сложно, и вы используете функции с побочными эффектами в LINQ, что не очень хорошо.

Вот более простое решение:

```
int[] scores = new int[] { 400, 651, 829, 651, 400, 405, 400 };
var valueToRank =
    scores.OrderBy(s => s)        // отсортировали по возрастанию
          .Select((s, idx) => (s, rank: idx + 1)) // раздали ранги
          .GroupBy(p => p.s)      // сгруппировали одинаковые значения
          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Average(p => p.rank)); // посчитали средний ранг 
                                                                  // по группе
```

Теперь у нас есть отображение значения в средний ранг, и можно подсчитать:

```
double[] ranks = scores.Select(s => valueToRank[s]).ToArray();
```

Проверяем:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{scores[i]} -> {ranks[i]}");
```

Результат:

```
400 -> 2
651 -> 5.5
829 -> 7
651 -> 5.5
400 -> 2
405 -> 4
400 -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно запоминать упорядоченный номер по порядку, затем вычислять среднее значение с помощью [`Average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var res = scores.Join(
            scores
                //упорядочиваем
                .OrderBy(score => score)
                //запоминаем упорядоченные позиции
                .Select((score, position) => new {Score = score, Position = position + 1})
                //группируем
                .GroupBy(x => x.Score)
                //выбираем ключ и среднее значение позиции
                .Select(g => new {Score = g.Key, Rang = g.Average(element => element.Position)}),
            o => o,
            i => i.Score,
            (o, i) => new {Score = o, i.Rang}
            );
```

Результат:

```
400 - 2
651 - 5,5
829 - 7
651 - 5,5
400 - 2
405 - 4
400 - 2
```

Comment: Join? Классный метод, да.

Comment: @VladD Да :), не стал его трогать, внес изменения только внутри